# Find corrupt files in cvs repository <ERROR filename,v is not a valid ,v file>

Tags: git, cvs, cvs2git

I am trying to migrate my repository from cvs to git using `cvs2git` but it fails when corrupt files are found. Is there anyway I can find corrupt files in CVS beforehand?

Command used :

```
cvs2git --blobfile=blobfilename --dumpfile=dumpfilename --retain-conflicting-attic-files --use-cvs --fallback-encoding=ascii -vvv --username=cvs2svn RepositoryPath
```

Output :

```
ERROR filename,v is not a valid ,v file
```

Comment: Put the detail how you do it and post the output you get

Answer (score 1):

try using /usr/bin/rcs I used it to read all the ,v files beforehand to locate any ,v files which are corrupt

Comment: Trouble is, this is effectively what the first stage of cvs2git does, so you're not really saving any time. Though I guess it will save you having to restart every time you find corruption as you would in cvs2git.

Comment: There are 100's of repositories which are to be converted. I want to run rcs on all these at one shot and fetch the corrupt ones :) Thanks  MyDeveloperDay and Mort

Comment: I found when running cvs2git that it wasn't until a later stage that the corruptions were found so sometimes I'd waste hours rerunning the conversion only for it to fail at the next file, so I found it easier to write a script that basic did   find . -name '*,v' -print -exec rcs <options> {} \;